# Firebase Crashlytics : We’ll be listening for your app to communicate with our servers

Tags: crashlytics

I have added latest firebase crashlytics dependencies as per google docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android

and did force crash app, but firebase crashlytics console stuck in "We’ll be listening for your app to communicate with our servers."
Anyone faced such issue please help screenshot -> [Firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgBdV.png)

Comment: Hi @Steve can u help me on this ,Thank you.

Comment: Did you enable Crashlytics from the Console? How did you force the crash? Are you using Dexguard if this is an Android app?